# Firestore: Wherein custom object array?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

im trying to make a sort of chat app with the following architecture:

[image: firestore architecture]

Its currently working as follows: in a root doc, there is an array of chat objects. Each chat object spawns a message doc, which contains an array of message objects. Same logic for comments.

Im thinking about a function to update all posts relative to the associated user, IE if a user changes their name all associated comments will be updated. Is this possible with the WhereIn() function? Or should i edit the architecture to something more like each document being its own message/comment? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [`in` clause](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) checks if a specific field is equal to one of a set of values, which doesn't apply here.

You might be thinking of `array-contains`, but that wouldn't work in your current structure either. The `array-contains` only matches exact an item in the array if it completely/exactly matches the value in the query.

The common way to allow such a query is to add a `participants` array field to each document where you store the UIDs of all participants in that doc. Then you can do an `array-contains` query against that.

Comment: I think that should work, thank you!